# changing the content dynamically using jquery slide in slide down

Tags: jquery

I have created a fiddle. In that the first li is constant where as the second li content keeps on changing. Currently its just changing the content dynamically. How can I change the second li content using jquery slide up slide down or fade in fade out so that teh change is visible to users. Can some body please help me in this?
http://jsfiddle.net/64ZNk/5/

```
<ol>
<li>
  <h4>1. One.</h4>
</li>
</ol>
<ol id="help">
<li>
  <h4>2. Two.</h4>
</li>
<li>
  <h4>3. Three.</h4>
</li>
</ol>
```

i tried with slideDown but its not coming correctly. Can somebody please help me in this
Updated fiddle with slideDown http://jsfiddle.net/64ZNk/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#help').append($(firstLi)).hide().fadeIn();
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/64ZNk/6/)

Comment: Hi Hiral..Thanks for ur reply. But this also doesn't make much difference..Is there a way where we can use slide up/slide down ? I tried like this $('#help').append($(firstLi)).hide().slideDown('slow'); but it is not coming correctly..Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/64ZNk/7/